# When integrating, does a change of variable have to apply to everything in the integrand?

Tags: integration

I have the following: $$\int_0^{\infty}re^{-\rho}\rho^{2l}L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\rho)L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\rho)dr,$$ where $L$ is the associated Laguerre polynomial. Is it possible to say that $r=\rho$ in order to get $$\int_0^{\infty}\rho e^{-\rho}\rho^{2l}L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\rho)L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\rho)d\rho$$ or would I have to change all the $\rho$s to $r$s as well, giving $$\int_0^{\infty}\rho e^{-r}\rho^{2l}L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(r)L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(r)d\rho?$$

Comment: I suspect that there is some dependence of $\rho$ on $r$ that you are not making explicit. However, taking what you have written as it stands, your first integral has the form $\int_0^{\infty}r \cdot f(\rho)dr$. This is equal to $f(\rho)\cdot\int_0^{\infty}rdr$ and  diverges unless $f$ is identically $0$.